# Does the 'move' tag serve any purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 299 questions tagged [move]. Some are about [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) move semantics, which is how I became aware of the tag. Some are about physical movement as in GPS or accelerometer. Some are about moving files (on assorted file systems, in assorted languages.)

Since it seems really unlikely anyone would use the tag in their interesting or their ignore lists, and since these questions usually have the word Move in the title, is there any point having the tag?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a meta tag to me. I can't think of any scenario where it could stand alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Research shows that it might serve some purpose, but it's complicated.

### **Long answer:**

As per the usage of [move](/questions/tagged/move), a random search by questions that are using it, shows users selecting it as:

1. **The verb** ["move"](http://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20move%20?&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=m7b&channel=fs&q=move&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=Clv3T765B42IhQfx_NjiBg&ved=0CFkQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9b0facc6b6dc2725&biw=1680&bih=858):

   ```
   Go in a specified direction or manner; change position
   ```

   Take this questions as an example, where the OPs intended to prevent the ability of moving files from A to B:

   - [Prevent a user from Deleting, Moving, or Renaming a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11318663/352449) also tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)
   - [Moving files into directory in foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3606438/352449) also tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php)
   - [Remove directory in hierarchy while preserving status in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335864/352449) also tagged with [git](/questions/tagged/git)
2. **A programming language called** [move](http://movelang.org/):

   > Move is a modern and simple programming language which can run on virtually any computer. Move is primarily aimed towards people not previously familiar with programming computers.

   - [Trying to install Move (movelang.org) using npm, but it's not being added to #!/usr/bin/env](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352223/352449) also tagged with [amazon-ec2](/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2)
3. **As a language-specific related to** [Phing - Core Tasks - move](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#MoveTask)

   > Moves a file or directory to a new file or directory. By default, the destination file is overwritten if it already exists. When overwrite is turned off, then files are only moved if the source file is newer than the destination file, or when the destination file does not exist.

   - [MoveTask in phing to slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5934556/352449) also tagged with [phing](/questions/tagged/phing)

---

**Summary:**

It is safe to assume that this tag really can't stand on its own, and should be removed, with the hard task of going through the 522 questions that are currently  using it, to either remove it; replace it with one that best fits there; or apply a language-specific one instead.

---

Despite the fact that your questions was placed over a year ago, and the [move](/questions/tagged/move) is mentioning that it was [created 2 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/move/info):

[image]

Fear not! She's already flagged to be removed as part of [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012):

[image]